# How to add new instruction and simulate it(spike)?

Tags: gcc, riscv

I want to add new instruction in the RISCV ISA, I follow the steps:

> Simulating a New Instruction. Adding an instruction to the simulator requires two steps:
>
> 1. Describe the instructions's functional behavior in the file `riscv/insns/<new_instruction_name>.h`. Examine other instructions in that directory as a starting point.
> 2. Add the opcode and opcode mask to `riscv/opcodes.h`. Alternatively, add it to the riscv-opcodes package, and it will do so for you: `$ cs ../riscv-opcodes`; `vi opcodes // add a line for the new instruction`; `make install`
> 3. Rebuild the sumulator.

[image]

And I write the simple assembly code to test:

```
.file   "hello.c"
.text
.align  2
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
   li   a0, 2
   mac  a1, a2, a3
   add  a0, a0, a1
.size main, .-main
.ident "GCC: (GNU)5.2.
```

[image]

But it can't recognize the new instruction (`mac a1,a2,a3`) with error message:

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc hello.s
...
hello.s:8: Error:unrecognized opcode `mac a1,a2,a3'
```

[image]

How should I do?

Comment: Please, post text not screenshots. You need to change assembler of [`riscv/riscv-tools`](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools), the message "`Error: unrecognized opcode \`mac a1,a2,a3'`" is from it. The list is in [`riscv/riscv-opcodes/`](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-opcodes) and the actual error message is from riscv-binutils - gas https://github.com/riscv/riscv-binutils-gdb/blob/master/gas/config/tc-riscv.c#L1187

Comment: I will post texts instead of screenshot next time.Thanks for your notice

Comment: Posting exact links to the external resources used in question may help too (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim#simulating-a-new-instruction, not partial screenshoot of text). I fixed image->text conversion for this question.

Comment: please read this https://nitish2112.github.io/post/adding-instruction-riscv/

Answer (score 1):

Your instruction (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim#simulating-a-new-instruction) is for adding the instruction to the simulator, not to assembler (binutils `as`/`gas`) which is called by your `gcc` command. The message "`Error: unrecognized opcode 'mac a1,a2,a3'`" is from assembler tool, there is the code to generate this error: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-binutils-gdb/blob/master/gas/config/tc-riscv.c#L1187

/* This routine assembles an instruction into its binary format.  As a
   side effect, it sets the global variable imm_reloc to the type of
   relocation to do if one of the operands is an address expression.  */

```
static const char *
riscv_ip (char *str, struct riscv_cl_insn *ip, expressionS *imm_expr,
      bfd_reloc_code_real_type *imm_reloc)
...
  const char *error = "unrecognized opcode";
  for ( ; insn && insn->name && strcmp (insn->name, str) == 0; insn++)
  {
  ...
  }
out:
  ...
  return error;
```

You can encode new instruction as raw bytes to use your current assembler; or you need to change assembler of [`riscv/riscv-tools`](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools), by changing the opcode list in [`riscv/riscv-opcodes/`](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-opcodes) and rebuilding your riscv-binutils (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-binutils-gdb) with the new riscv-opcodes.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,I have already changed the opcode list in  [risv/riscv-opcodes/](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-opcodes/tree/7650b391d47dd0b73d541d39c48041aa53517973) and I make install . I also described the instruction's functional behavior in the file [riscv/insns/](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/tree/master/riscv/insns).
Finally,I added the instruction in [riscv-binutils-gdb/opcodes/riscv-opc.c](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-binutils-gdb/blob/riscv-next/opcodes/riscv-opc.c).
But it still gives me errors(I can't rebuild the gnu-tool-chain).Which step that I do wrong?

Comment: jjlin, the wrong step was when you created wrong question. In this question you linked only instruction for changing the simulator. Rebuild error of gnu toolchain is the different error (we need more details about it) and it is hard to debug such errors for free (next your question on stackoverflow may be closed as offtopic). Start from non-modified riscv toolchains and learn how to rebuild them (will other OS help, find recent instruction) before doing any custom changes.